# no integer solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider $$nq\left(n+2q+2^23j  \right)=2^23^2j^3$$

where all variables are positive integers.  It appears there are no integer solutions.

Specific cases i think are easy to see for example if $j=1$, then you can simply reason the small finite cases of $n,q$.  I'm guessing you could probably move through all possibilities of $n,q$ with general $j$ (noting $nq<3j^2$)  However is there a more robust approach?

Comment: If $A \times B$ is an integer, must $A$ be an integer?

Comment: @CalvinLin i assume your comment applies to my last question regarding asymptotic matching? if so i take your point.  The approach here isn't going to scale well when polynomial on the left, in $2^13^1j^1$ becomes higher in order and the coefficients involving $n,q$ also increase in order.  Is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: No, it applies to $2q=6js-n$. We could have the term be a fraction, since we're multiplying by $nq$. E.g. $\frac{1}{2} \times 2 = 1$, or if $nq=j$, that would cancel out the fraction.

Comment: @CalvinLin  Ahhh yes i see it.  Gotch ya.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Calvin.  I've backed out the Edit and left the question in its original form.

Comment: @user25025 Can we take $n=j=0$ ?

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit.  No.  All variables are strictly positive i'm afraid.  I think i have patched up my proof and may post an Edit shortly,